# How do I prevent a literal from causing its container to grow?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I have an ASP.NET 2010 web app. In it I have a gridview with an Ajax editor control in the footer. Users can add comments via the editor control and when they click submit the comments are rendered in a literal in the grid. This workd well unless some wiseguy puts a long unbreaking string of characters. I successfully got the literal to wrap by putting it in a div and setting a style. However, even though the text wraps in the literal, the `<TD>` that it resides in still grows as it the text was spread out across it. I tried using the overflow style on the TD but couldn't get it to work.

I should clarify....this is a gridview. In the gridview is a table. In the table is the literal.

Here is my code in part...

```
<fieldset class="mediumDisplay">
    <div style="word-wrap:break-word;">
         <asp:Literal ID="litComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("Comments"))%>' Mode="Transform"></asp:Literal>
    </div>                           
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set an explicit width on the enclosing div, that should get your overflow setting to take effect.  Without a width, the DIV will happily expand to accommodate its contents, and the overflow will never take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enabling wrapping in the ItemStyle of the column?

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="200px" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```